# Even larger Windows mouse pointer

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

Windows 10 lets me select normal, large, and extra large, but even the largest setting looks quite small on a small high-resolution display.

Is there a tool that could help make the mouse pointer even bigger?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, besides increasing size, to improve visibility of the mouse pointer. My favorite is to make it 'inverted' so that it is white while on a dark background and black while on a light background. See [this link](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/3-ways-to-change-mouse-pointer-size-and-color-in-windows-10.html) for details on how to do it.

You can also show mouse trails, which help to see where the mouse is when it is moving; instructions available at [this link](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/display-or-hide-mouse-pointer-trails-in-windows-10.html).

You can have a blinking circle appear around the mouse when you hold down the Ctrl key; instructions available at [this link](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/show-pointer-location-with-ctrl-key-in-windows-10.html).

If you really want a custom cursor [Stardock's CursorFX](https://www.stardock.com/products/cursorfx/) does a great job. CursorFX has a number of built-in cursors, animated cursors, sound effects for your mouse clicks and lets you create your own cursors. There are also thousands of pre-made cursors for CursorFX available at [WinCustomize](https://www.wincustomize.com/explore/cursorfx).

If you just want a basic really large cursor you can try the xxl cursors available at [rw-designer](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-set/xxl).

Comment: The Control key trick is my favourite, but I will check out some of the others (+1).